# HL7 - FN DataType inside XCN DataType?

Tags: hl7, hl7-v2

I'm taking a look in [Caristix HL7 v2.5 - Segment PV1](https://hl7-definition.caristix.com/v2/HL7v2.5/Segments/PV1):

[image: Caristix Website]

And when I click PV1.9 DataType it shows DataType fields:

[image: Caristix Website 2]

In XCN.2 shows FN as DataType, and FN is not just a string:

[image: Caristix Website 3]

So, how can I make an example of HL7 with PV1.9 having datatype XCN that has FN inside too? I don't get it

*Trying to make an example*

```
MSH|^~\&|SA|SF||R|201802201803^450||ADT^A01^ADT_A01|2018022018035210|P|2.2||||||
EVN|A01|201802201803|||SHE7|
PV1|1|E|||||||1^Surname&Own Surname Prefix&Own Surname&Surname Prefix From Partner/Spouse&Surname From Partner/Spouse^||||
```

But it seems like is not right :(

Comment: You have it right. Some field components will contain subcomponents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After testing the message with different parsers, the way HL7 works for subcomponents are like this:

```
MSH|^~\&|SA|SF||R|201802201803^450||ADT^A01^ADT_A01|2018022018035210|P|2.2||||||
EVN|A01|201802201803|||SHE7|
PV1|1|E|||||||1^Surname&Own Surname Prefix&Own Surname&Surname Prefix From Partner/Spouse&Surname From Partner/Spouse^||||
```

Using **Subcomponent separator** character (&)

Then, parsed items will be like this

```
PV1
 |- PV1.1
 |  |- SI
 |    |- 1
 |- PV1.2
 |  |- IS
 |    |- E
 |- PV1.9
 |  |- PV1.9.1
 |    |- ST
 |      |- 1
 |  |- PV1.9.2
 |    |- XCN
 |      |- Surname
 |      |- Own Surname Prefix
 |      |- Surname Prefix From Partner/Spouse
 |      |- Surname Form Partner/Spouse
```

That's right.

Answer (score 1):

The [`XCN - Extended Composite ID Number and Name for Persons`](https://hl7-definition.caristix.com/v2/HL7v2.5/DataTypes/XCN) datatype holds identifier, name (separated by components) and some additional information. Note that most of the fields in datatype are `O` (optional), `C` (conditional) or `B` (for backward compatibility).

In `XCN`, as said above, you can hold [`XCN.2 - Family Name`](https://hl7-definition.caristix.com/v2/HL7v2.5/DataTypes/XCN.2) which holds the datatype [`FN - Family Name`](https://hl7-definition.caristix.com/v2/HL7v2.5/DataTypes/FN) which is just a string.

> This data type allows full specification of the surname of a person. Where appropriate, it differentiates the person's own surname from that of the person's partner or spouse, in cases where the person's name may contain elements from either name. It also permits messages to distinguish the surname prefix (such as "van" or "de") from the surname root.

So basically, its a string separated by components. Your value becomes something like below:

```
IdNumber^FamilyName^GivenName^SecondAndFurtherGivenNamesOrInitialsThereof^Suffix^Prefix
```

Your `PV1` segment becomes something like below:

```
PV1|1|E|||||||IdNumber^FamilyName^GivenName^SecondAndFurtherGivenNamesOrInitialsThereof^Suffix^Prefix||||
```

You may further refer [`PV1`](https://corepointhealth.com/resource-center/hl7-resources/hl7-pv1-patient-visit-information-segment/) segment.

You are just confused due to deep hierarchy or nested datatypes. If you map those to your programming language, it becomes quite simple.

Comment: Family name for v2.5 is not a string.